# Source (src) tag of my .js file (jquery) is being modified automatically on my web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have created an MVC application and hosted it on a server.

Yesterday I noticed when a user clicks on a link it opens an advertisement in another window.

I tried to identify what is happening using Google Chrome’s Developer tool and found that src of my script tag is being modified automatically (image is attached).

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

In the above image, my src of .js file is modified

The actual src I have used in my code.

The first image contains the actual src in my code

[image]

The second image contains the tempered src

[image]
In the background, I was using fiddler and saw this message there.
**This can be caused by an illegal HTTP response earlier on this reused server socket-- for instance, a HTTP/304 response which illegally contains a body.**

Comment: According to your description, I still couldn't understand the issue clearly. You mean someone modify the page's js reference link and add the advertisement? This just happened on just one user or all the users?  I suggest you could re-check the server's codes to make sure there is no difference between the development production environment.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to 'Man in the middle' attack. I installed an SSL certificate and the problem is solved.